# Can not open exported excel file in ExcelJS

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-excel, exceljs

I have used **ExcelJS** libary in my JS project. It works fine with English letters. But if I change my application language in to **French** and export the content as a excel sheet. Then the below mentioned error is coming. Anyone know what cause this issue and a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I am using ExcelJS to convert/create an excel file using my fin-hypergrid table. The reason which caused this issue is in my fin-hypergrid table I had two columns with same name. Then excelJS will add unknown character at the end of the column name. That was the reason, which cause the above error.